# Почему не идет выборка из базы?

Tags: php, mysql

Здравствуйте. Есть таблица **prod** , в ней ячейка *id_specz* , в которой значение **3,2,1**

Я делаю выборку из базы следующим запросом:

```
$vib = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `prod` WHERE `id_specz` IN (".$numbers.") ORDER BY `id` DESC");
```

Если переменная **$numbers** = 3 - запись находит. А если переменная = 2 или 1 - запись не находит. 
Еще нужно учесть то, что переменная **$numbers** может иметь значения *2,3* или *1,3* и так далее.

Что я делаю не так? 
P.S. О том что MySQL устарела - я в курсе, проект древний, вношу правки.

Буду очень благодарен за помощь.

Comment: потому что в ячейке не должно быть значений вида 3,2,1

Comment: @Ипатьев но они есть

Comment: MySQL совсем не устарела, устарели функции `mysql_*`. У вас проблемы с типами ячеек в таблице.

Comment: @D-side да......

Comment: @fens **mysql_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given**

Comment: @fens та же ошибка

Comment: `"SELECT * FROM \`prod\` WHERE FIND_IN_SET( \`id_specz\`, '".$numbers."') ORDER BY \`id\` DESC"` и начитесь читать ошибки....

Answer (score 0):

Вот решение. Надеюсь.

```
<?php 
    require_once 'ФАЙЛ_ПОДКЛЮЧЕНИЯ_К_БД.php'; //подключение к БД
    //$connection - это переменная с подключением. У вас, возможно, другая.

    //Получаем и упорядочиваем данные из БД
    $query = "SELECT prod.id, prod.id_specz FROM prod";
    $result = $connection->query($query);
    if (!$result) {die($connection->error);};
    $new_arr=[]; //массив с уже отстортированными данными
    while ($myrow = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
        $id_specz=$myrow['id_specz'];
        if (iconv_strlen($id_specz)>1) {
            $d=explode(',', $id_specz); //режем строку по запятой
            sort($d); //спортируем знаечения по возрастанию
            $id_specz=implode(',', $d); //соединяем в строку
        }
        $new_arr[$myrow['id']]=$id_specz;
    };

    unset($result); //удаляем ненужное

    //Теперь обновим БД. Используем транзакцию, чтобы гарантировать запись.
    //Тут я использую одну для всей работы. Но если база большая, то лучше разбить на несколько частей и использовать подготовленные выражения (погуглите)
    $connection->autocommit(false); 
        foreach ($new_arr as $key => $value) {
            $query = "UPDATE prod SET id_specz = '$value' WHERE id = '$key'  LIMIT 1";
            $result = $connection->query($query);
            if (!$result) {die($connection->error);};
        }
    if (!$connection->commit()) {die($connection->error);};


    //Теперь у нас в БД всё упорядочено и приведено к единому виду. Можно с ними работать нормально.
    $want_to_find='1,2'; //ищем такую строку
    $query = "SELECT * FROM prod WHERE prod.id_specz = '$want_to_find'";
    $result = $connection->query($query);
    if (!$result) {die($connection->error);};
    while ($myrow = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
        echo $myrow['id'].'<br>';
    };
?>
```

Если нужно искать все варианты (т.е. если вы хотите найти все записи, где есть 2 - например 1,2,3 или 1,2), то используйте

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM prod WHERE prod.id_specz SOUNDS LIKE '$want_to_find'";
```

Тут можно тогда не приводить к единому виду. Но лучше всё же привести.

Comment: с чего вы взяли что в таблице есть id по мимо id_specz ? И зачем все эти танцы с бубном с выборкой всех записей потом обновлением,  только для сортировки одного значения?

Comment: через мин 10 проверю как оно :) спасибо

Comment: @fens Всегда с радостью посмотрю на лучшее решение проблемы. Тут следовало привести записи к единому виду. Я привёл. Буду рад узнать что-то новое.

Comment: @Денис обратите внимание в самом низу ответа на SOUNDS LIKE

Comment: обратите внимание на тот факт, что если автор вопроса заявляет, будто правильное решение у него не работает, то это не означает, что надо со всех ног кидаться и изобретать кривые костыли. иногда надо просто постучать автору по голове, до тех пор пока до него не дойдет правильное решение.

Comment: @n.osennij кто вам сказал что их нужно привести к единой записи? информации про значения хранящиеся в `id_specz` нет, а так как изначальный запрос выглядит как ... `id_specz` IN (".$numbers.") ... я делаю вывод о том что в $numbers приезжает либо 1 либо несколько значений в виде строки, а вот в колонке содержится одно значение, вот так размышлял я и поэтому вижу достаточным для решения задачи использовать FIND_IN_SET. А вот как вы пришли к выводу что необходимо что то в БД нормализовать мне вообще не понятно...

Comment: @fens Я переписывался с автором в ответе, который удалил до этого (соответственно удалились все комментарии). Так вот, я уточнил у автора тип данных этого столбца, в каком виде конкретно данные там хранятся и все их особенности. И пришёл к выводу, что их нужно нормализовать.

Comment: @Ипатьев И что вы считаете правильным решением?

Comment: правильное решение для этой банальной задачи дали в комментариях к вопросу еще час назад.